# slideDown div inside a function not working

Tags: jquery

For now I'm trying to slide down the msg_general div, I will later append a json response to it, however the problem is it will just show but not slidedown.

The function:

```
function createGeneralMsg(msg) {
   $('#msg_general').slideDown(200);
}
```

Where I call it (inside a .click functon):

```
.......
$.ajax({                    
type: "POST",
url: action_link,
data: data_string,
dataType: 'json',
success:
    function(msg) {
        if($('.delete-link').hasClass('delete-page')) {
            window.location = 'index.php';
        }
        if($('.delete-link').hasClass('delete-news')) {
            createGeneralMsg(msg);
        }
    }
}, 'json');
.......
```

slideDown() will work anywhere else, when I test this for example:

```
$('.test').click(function() {
    $('#msg_general').slideDown(200);
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to call it on coplate event :

```
var _msg;

$.ajax({                    
type: "POST",
url: action_link,
data: data_string,
dataType: 'json',
success:
    function(msg) {
        if($('.delete-link').hasClass('delete-page')) {
            window.location = 'index.php';
        }
    }
},
complete : function() { 

    if($('.delete-link').hasClass('delete-news')) {
        createGeneralMsg(_msg);
    }
},

//code goes on here...
```